# Do I ever get xp for my party member's kills?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've heard xp "Is not split" in D3 parties, but to whom is it given?

If there are a dozen monsters on the screen worth 100xp each, and my partner kills them all with some nuke (while I idly watch) do we each get 1200xp?

If so, and he kills the same batch of monsters while I am very far away, do I still get the xp?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

XP is **duplicated** for each party members within "a screen and a half"<sup>[1](https://twitter.com/#!/Bashiok/statuses/166765857983307776)</sup> of the kill, as if each member got the kill themselves. (Though all party members will get quest-end XP regardless of location.)

This is a departure from *Diablo 2*, where XP was literally divided among party members.

In your example, yes, you each would get 1200 XP, but not if you're far away ("screen and a half").

Comment: So you are saying the xp is individual for each party member with a max range of a screen and a half, am I right following this logic?

Comment: Yep, identical as long as you're within range of the kill

Comment: Is the size of the "screen and a half" based on something in-game or dependent on the player's resolution?

Comment: In-game, but that rough estimate came from Bashiok, a Blizzard CM. If you want him to clarify, you can ask him directly

Comment: Note that any +exp-per-kill bonuses **are not** duplicated.  My friend and I played hardcore, me at level 10 and him at 1.  To catch up, he added a bunch of +exp bonuses, while I had none.  Though we always stuck together and never died, by the time I was level 20 he was ahead of me.

Answer (score 9):

As long as you are in the same area as the kill occurs, you will each get the full experience for the kill.  I believe the no splitting refers to the fact that it it isn't divided by the number of players.