# In co-op, when does the level difference XP penalty kick in?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How does experience work in groups of heroes with different levels?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67065/how-does-experience-work-in-groups-of-heroes-with-different-levels)

I know that, if you're playing with a character who's significantly higher level than you, you receive a penalty to XP gained from killing monsters. But how big does the difference need to be to kick in?

I've seen 5 levels kicked around, but I haven't been able to find any credible source for the information.

Here's a question from a [developer Q&A](http://d3db.com/news/id/216-best-buy-developer-qa-transcript/) mentioning the penalty, but no specifics:

> **Guest-236:** If i am higher level then my freinds and want to play with them, will there be any kind of handicap? for example will they get less exp
>
> **JasonBender:** To Guest-236 There is an XP penalty for killing monsters too high/low in level relative to your character. It scales based on your level, so at lower levels you can fight a broader range of creatures. This is good because player levels tend to be farther apart earlier in the game.

Comment: Not sure why that question would be a duplicate of this, as it doesn't not mention the XP penalty for having a party member of much higher level at all.

Comment: If this is just a question about the penalty for killing monsters of lower level, it should be reworded. As is, it sounds like a duplicate. It mentions co-op in the title.

Answer (score 2):

The lower level player gets full exp from my experience.

Blizzard devs have touched on this briefly:

http://forums.battle.net/thread.html?topicId=27804720356&postId=278022081479&sid=3000#5

More discussion Here:

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149617388?page=3

Comment: I think your answer is correct, could you move it to the question linked as a duplicate so it isn't lost when this question gets closed?

Comment: The penalty definitely exists; please see my edit.