# How much experience is required for each level?

Tags: diablo-iii

I looked around and I could not find a table of how much experience is required for each level. Various other questions and answers relate experience based on the [number of levels gained](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67065/how-does-experience-work-in-groups-of-heroes-with-different-levels) - but it is hard to make an accurate comparison without knowing how much experience is required for each level.  So how much experience is required per level?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the folks over at the [Diablo 3 Database Forums](http://d3db.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=15) has provided a google doc for just this purpose!

[Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlA6XxR3FQO_dHJHMHo0b1piR2w5bzBQM1VWM0c2ZHc#gid=0)

And from that data, we get this nifty chart:
[image]

That big spike is at Level 50, just before Hell difficulty starts.

Comment: So basically they artificially make sure that you finish Nightmare at level 50?

Comment: @bwarner I've heard there's a similar jump at 30 and normal (though it's ~150% instead of ~200%, and less visible)

Comment: What beautiful SCIENCE!

Comment: @RavenDreamer There very much isn't a similar jump in XP per level at level 30, according to the google doc and this chart...I checked, and the XP increase from 29 to 30 is about 2%, same for level 30 to level 31. Unless you're saying you think the Google doc is incorrect about that.

Comment: @bwarner it makes some sense - the jump between the end of Nightmare and the beginning of Hell is super frustrating to deal with, although that's more a gear issue and not a level issue.