# XP mechanics for different levels coop in console Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii-console

Let's consider a case when there's a game with three 15 level character and one 1 level.
What will happen with monsters and experience in this case? I am talking about local co-op on the same screen, not multiplayer.

I mean what level of monsters should we expect? Will it be playable for both types of players (for example, 15 level monsters I guess will one shot the 1 level character)?

And how much experience will be getting by 1 level character? 15 level characters? How fast will they balance in levels?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here, and some of them are off topic here - "How fast will they balance in levels" is based off how good you are at the game, how quickly you complete objectives, etc - you could spend 4 hours dying against the same enemy (for example) and in this case, you won't balance at all. "How much experience will be got by the level 1/15 character" depends on what you're killing, whether you have experience shrines, what your +XP per kill/+XP% values are on a per character basis, etc...

Comment: If I should clarify the exact case, I'll do this with pleasure. Let's firstly get rid of all bonuses, so there's no +XP per kill gear, there's no any experience shrines, also I don't want to know the exact period of time when the characters will balance in levels, I just need to know what is more effective - to play such a game or to play solo from level 1 to level 15 and then join cooperative play. Also I realize the fact that we can start playing from the beginning and from the place where the highest-level character ended up - I'm interestred in both cases (what monsters should we expect).

Comment: Nope, I don't think you understand - ok so we'll ignore bonuses and whatever, what about taking into consideration the random enemy spawns, random special spawns, random level spawns, etc Asking "when will we level out" or any similar question about a game that has random level generation is never going to get you an answer that is useful.

Comment: @ZZa Perhaps editing your question to ask what you just said might be better. "**Will I gain more experience playing solo or playing with a local co-op group?**" Or specifically your use case: "**What is the most effective way level up?** Solo or co-op? Is there a particular area that provides a better XP yield or perhaps a boss that can be re-run with ease for better XP gain?" Asking for a strategy in stead of a specific solution to a randomly derived circumstance might help to tighten this question up.

Comment: You could also simply ask what effect higher level co-op partners will have on your XP gain. This is essentially what your current question almost gets at when it asks what the effect on monster level and XP distro will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monsters spawn in zones.  Zones determine the levels and kinds of monsters.  This is the same regardless of the number of players.

Scenario one: Solo level 15 in a level 15 zone.  Fights enemies and gets some amount of xp per kill (suppose it's 20 xp).

Scenario two: Two level 15s in a level 15 zone.  Fights enemies.  Each player gets the same xp per kill as the soloer in scenario one (each player gets 20 xp for each dying monster).  Adding a player increases monster hitpoints and quantity spawned.

What about level differences?

Well that's answered over here: [How does experience work in groups of heroes with different levels?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67065/how-does-experience-work-in-groups-of-heroes-with-different-levels)
The only difference on console is that you are never out-of-range to earn xp.  So xp is always copied perfectly between characters playing together (except with death, untested).

> Will it be playable for both types of players?

No.  Level 15 monsters will destroy level 1 characters.  Level 1 monsters will not reward level 15 characters.