# How does +xp per kill on a follower works

Tags: diablo-iii

When I equip a +xp per kill item on a follower, How is the extra xp gained? I've read already that I'll get only 20% of the bonus (so a +5xp will become +1xp) but, will I get it for every kill made by both of us (the player and the follower) or will it be given only for kills done by the follower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All kills by the follower act exactly the same as monsters you've killed yourself.  What that means is that you take 20% of the follower's bonus, add it to your's, and then apply that to all kills done by either of you.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Do I ever get xp for my party member's kills?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63605/do-i-ever-get-xp-for-my-party-members-kills)

As for the fixed number in experience items ("+5 xp") I believe that adds an extra 5 points of experience with each kill